# Invalid hidden shortcuts in user folder

Tags: windows-7

I was trying to customize my StartMenu, and showed hidden files. If I go Computer -> users -> *username*, I see shortcuts for: AppData, Application data, local settings, start menu, and a few others. All of these, besides AppData, throw an `{foldername} is not accessible. Access is denied` error.

Is this normal?

I found something about `%appdata%`, so if I do `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` I can get into the folder.

Is there a good way to correct the shortcuts? I tried doing file>new> new shortcut - and used the path above, but I have the shortcut I just made, and the invalid one (which is listed as a folder - in Details view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Junction points

Yes, that's normal. Those aren't standard shortcuts, rather [junctions points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) used for compatibility reasons:

> In Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008, the default locations for user data and system data have changed. For example, user data that was previously stored in the `%SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings` directory is now stored in the `%SystemDrive%\Users` directory.
>
> Per-user junctions are created inside each individual user's profile to provide backward compatibility for user applications. The junction point at `C:\Users\username\My Documents` that points to `C:\Users\username\Documents` is an example of a per-user junction.
>
> <sub>Source: [Junction Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

Since their only purpose is to avoid possible issues with old programs, the user is not meant to actually explore them, and so they denied the **List folder / read data** permissions to **Everyone**. If you were to change the permissions, you wouldn't get an "access denied" error anymore, and reach the target folder instead (e.g. `Local Settings --> C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local`).

## Further reading

- [NTFS junction point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point)
- [Junction Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I have used Junctions before in another context. Can you comment on the broken junction points?

Comment: @RyanB I've updated my answer. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks for adding that blurb. I guess that users can only truly get there via `%appdata%/...` adds an additional layer of security.